# Understand EXPLAIN mysql

Tags: mysql, explain

I am trying to interpret the explain of mysql on a query,this is the table:

```
    create table text_mess(
    datamess timestamp(3) DEFAULT 0,
    sender bigint ,
    recipient bigint ,
    roger boolean,
    msg char(255),
    foreign key(recipient) 
            references users (tel) 
                        on delete cascade
                        on update cascade,
primary key(datamess,sender)
)
engine = InnoDB
```

this is the first type of query :

```
    EXPLAIN
    select /*!STRAIGHT_JOIN*/datamess, sender,recipient,roger,msg
    from text_mess join (select max(datamess)as dmess
                    from text_mess 
                    where roger = true
                    group by sender,recipient) as max
                    on text_mess.datamess=max.dmess ;
```

and this is the second:EXPLAIN

```
    EXPLAIN
    select /*!STRAIGHT_JOIN*/datamess, sender,recipient,roger,msg
    from  (select max(datamess)as dmess
                    from text_mess 
                    where roger = true
                    group by sender,recipient) as max
      join
    text_mess
    on max.dmess = text_mess.datamess ;
```

the two queries are asking the same thing, the only difference is the order of ref_table (driving_table), in the first case is text_mess, in the second case is a sub query :
![first and second query][1]

as you can see the difference is in the order of the first two lines, my question in particular is on the second (the faster query )
the second line should be the inner-table, but if so, why the column ref tells me: max.dmess, that should be the column of the ref-table (sub-query).
and, the last row is referred on how the first is built?
and in the end you think there is a more efficient query?